# WSO2 IS continuous error on too many opened files

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

In `wso2carbon.log` I am seeing the following log being printed continuously indicating that there are `Too many open files`.

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-05-28 10:31:46,495] ERROR {org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Acceptor} - Socket accept failed java.io.IOException: Too many open files
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:424)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:252)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.serverSocketAccept(NioEndpoint.java:546)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.serverSocketAccept(NioEndpoint.java:79)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Acceptor.run(Acceptor.java:129)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

TID: [-1234] [] [2023-05-28 10:32:44,162] ERROR {org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Acceptor} - Socket accept failed java.io.IOException: Too many open files
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:424)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:252)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.serverSocketAccept(NioEndpoint.java:546)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.serverSocketAccept(NioEndpoint.java:79)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Acceptor.run(Acceptor.java:129)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above error is occurring due to the **soft** and **hard** file limits not being correctly set in the platform. To check the **soft** and **hard** file limits you can execute the following command in the terminal.

```
ulimit -Sn 
ulimit -Hn
```

If those values do not align with the performance tuning recommendations suggested by WSO2 you have to set those values properly[1]. Make sure to restart the platform if necessary.

1. https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/6.0.0/deploy/performance/performance-tuning-recommendations/